# Recommended foam firmness for shipping

Tags: foam

I'm wondering if there is any paper or study regarding the recommended firmness of foam for best packaging?

Best packaging is seen here as most efficient to endure and absorb shocks during shipping.

Packaging firmness can be more or less hard or soft.

[image]

For instance, you usually see soft foam packaging for jewelry and hard/tough foam packaging for TV/screen.

My first analysis is that the heavier the item is, the harder the foam packaging should be. Has there any serious study?

Comment: I doubt there is a one-size-fits-all calculation because packaging depends on the sturdiness, size and shape of the object as well as the weight. Marketing aspects play a role, too. A game controller doesn't need half as much foam as depicted in your image, but a big package full of foam looks more valuable than a small package without foam. Can you [edit] your post and add some details about what exactly your goal or problem is? What kind of object do you want to package?

Comment: And are you actually looking for a proper way to pack something, or for an existing study? This is not really the proper place to ask for the latter.

Comment: Having packed some very fragile things in the past (for work), if it's both heavy and fragile it's tricky, but you have a point.  More than one layer can often be best - the inner layer can be a bit softer and designed to evenly support the object, also protecting it from chips and scratches, and the outer layer protects from crushing and dropping.  This could be an outer layer of foam, but it could be a crate or a cardboard box.  So much depends on what you're packing and how it's being transported - and that's why this is a comment; there simply isn't a single answer.

Comment: It sounds like you want a paper on best practices. Such a paper would be most likely produced by an industry group for the shipping industry. Try doing a search with different combinations of "packing material" "industry" best practice" etc. I'm sure something like this exists; it won't be "one answer" but rather a discussion of best options for different combinations of weight/size/shape/shipping method.